# Boostrap modal not showing up after clicking href

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to show a pop modal after a user clicks a particular link on my page. I cannot however get the modal to actually pop up.

This is what I have tried:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#Modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Modal Control</a>
<div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$('a[href$="#Modal"]').on( "click", function() {
  $('#Modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: You are missing jQuery!

Comment: @Coli what do you mean

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: @j08691 no errors, nothing happens

Comment: You need to load jQuery to use `$` and Bootstrap! Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: Works fine for me https://www.codeply.com/p/MHZvdspxzq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use javascript. Just use data-toggle & data-target.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Modal Control</a>
    <div id="Modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works fine as-is provided the OP included jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery before popper and bootstrap.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Working Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href$="#Modal"]').on("click", function() {
    $("#Modal").modal("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- BootStrap 4 CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- BootStrap 4 JS -->
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>


    <title>Open Modal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#Modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Modal Control</a>
    <div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting the same issue

Comment: Have you placed the script at the end of the HTML? Because your code is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `href="#Modal"` from `<a href="#Modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Modal Control</a>` and give any id ↓↓

```
<a id="modal_link" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Modal Control</a>
```

```
$('#modal_link').on("click", function() {
    $('#Modal').modal('show');
});
```

This should work. 
**Edit--**
And yes you're missing jQuery library--

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```